# How to split up long HTML into "functions"

Tags: html, templates

When writing a non-trivial static HTML page, the large-scale structure gets very hard to see, with the fine structure and the content all mixed into it. Scrolling several pages to find the closing tag that matches a given opening tag is frustrating. In general it feels messy, awkward, and hard to maintain... like writing a large program with no functions.

Of course, when I write a large program, I break it up hierarchically into smaller functions. Is there any way to do this with a large HTML file?

Basically I'm looking for a template system, where the content to be inserted into the template is just more HTML that's optionally (here's the important part) *located in the same file.*

That is, I want to be able to do something like what is suggested by this hypothetical syntax:

```
<html>
    <head>{{head}}</head>
    <body>
        <div class="header">{{header}}</div>
        <div class="navbar">{{navbar}}</div>
        <div class="content">{{content}}</div>
        <div class="footer">{{footer}}</div>
    </body>
</html>

{{head}} =
    <title>Hello World!</title>
    {{styles}}
    {{scripts}}
{{styles}} = 
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
{{navbar}} =
    ...
    ...
    ... and so on...
```

Then presumably there would be a simple way to "compile" this to make a standard HTML file.

Are there any tools out there to allow writing HTML this way?

Most template engines require each include to be a separate file, which isn't useful.

**UPDATE**: [Gnu M4](http://www.gnu.org/software/m4/m4.html) seems to do exactly the sort of thing I'm looking for, but with a few caveats:

1. The macro definitions have to appear before they are used, when I'd rather they be after.
2. M4's syntax mixes very awkwardly with HTML. Since the file is no longer HTML, it can't be easily syntax checked for errors. The M4 processor is very forgiving and flexible, making errors in M4 files hard to find sometimes - the parser won't complain, or even notice, when what you wrote means something other than what you probably meant.
3. There's no way to get properly indented HTML out, making the output an unreadable mess. (Since production HTML might be minified anyway, that's not a major issue, and it can always be run through a formatter if it needs to be readable.)

Comment: try freemarker templates

Comment: Maybe jade? http://jade-lang.com/

Comment: [Thymeleaf layouts](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/layouts.html)

Comment: as far as I can see, freemarker and jade are like most other template engines I know of - they're designed to take a template and data, and they insert the data into the template. They can't insert part of the template into another part. And Thymeleaf can include other files. Imagine a programming language that required you to put every function in a separate file!

Answer (score 0):

This will parse your template example and do what you want.

```
perl -E 'my $pre.=join("",<>); my ($body,%h)=split(/^\{\{(\w+)\}\}\s*=\s*$/m, $pre); while ($body =~ s/\{\{(\w+)\}\}/$h{$1}/ge) { if ($rec++>200) {die("Max recursion (200)!")}};$body =~ s/({{)-/$1/sg; $body =~ s/({{)-/$1/sg; print $body' htmlfiletoparse.html
```

And here's the script version.
file joshTplEngine ;)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

## get/read lines from files. Multiple input files are supported
my $pre.=join("",<>); 

## split files to body and variables %h = hash
## variable is [beginning of the line]{{somestring}} = [newline]
my ($body,%h)=split(/^\{\{# split on variable line and 
(\w+) ## save name
\}\} 
\s*=\s*$/xm, $pre); 

## replace recursively all variables defined as {{somestring}}
while ($body =~ s/
   \{\{
      (\w+) ## name of the variable
   \}\}
  / ##
    $h{$1} ## all variables have been read to hash %h and $1 contens variable name from mach
    /gxe) { 
    ## check for number of recursions, limit to 200
    if ($rec++>200) {
        die("Max recursion (200)!")
    }
}
## replace {{- to {{ and -}} to }}
$body =~ s/({{)-/$1/sg;
$body =~ s/-(}})/$1/sg;
## end, print
print $body;
```

Usage:

```
joshTplEngine.pl /some/html/file.html [/some/other/file] | tee /result/dir/out.html
```

I hope this little snipped of perl will enable you to your templating.